# Absence of spacing between the Figure name (number of the figure) and the Figure Caption

Tags: bookmarks

In the List of Figures, the space between the Figure name and the caption (with a dash in the middle) did not keep the same when the number of Figure name increase as following:
Figure 6.9 - Original (red) and .... (it is OK)
Figure 6.10-Original (red) and  .... (it is not OK: the spacing was lost)

The latex code that I am using to generate the **List of Figures** is:
`\pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}`
`\listoffigures*`
`\cleardoublepage`\

[image: Text]

**Main TEX file:**

```
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}    %Alterar o idioma padrão do documento
\frontmatter
\pretextual
\imprimircapa
\setcounter{page}{2}
\imprimirfolhaderosto
\imprimirfolhadeaprovacao
\input{Pretextual/agradecimentos.tex}
\input{Pretextual/resumo.tex}
\input{Pretextual/abstract.tex}
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{2.7em}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures*
\cleardoublepage
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{2.7em}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables*
\cleardoublepage
\input{Pretextual/Lista_Siglas.tex}
\input{Pretextual/Lista_Simbolos.tex}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{\thepage}
\textual
\input{Chap_1/Chap_1.tex}
\input{Chap_2/Chap_2.tex}
\input{Chap_3/Chap_3.tex}
\input{Chap_4/Chap_4.tex}
\input{Chap_5/Chap_5.tex}
\input{Chap_6/Chap_6.tex}
\input{Chap_7/Chap_7.tex}
\input{Chap_8/Chap_8.tex}
\postextual
\bibliographystyle{abntex2-alf-VerUnicamp}
\bibliography{Thesis.bib}
\begin{apendicesenv}
    \partapendices %GERA UMA PÁGINA EM BRANCO COM A PALAVRA APÊNDICE
    \input{Apendice/ApendiceA.tex}
    \input{Apendice/ApendiceB.tex}
%   \input{Apendice/ApendiceC.tex}
\end{apendicesenv}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%ANEXOS
%\begin{anexosenv}
%   \partanexos
%   \input{Anexos/AnexoA.tex}
%\end{anexosenv}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

**Preambulo TEX file:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper, chapter=TITLE, english, english, sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter} 
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}
\usepackage[alf, abnt-etal-cite=2, abnt-etal-list=0, abnt-etal-text=emph, abnt-and-type=e, abnt-last-names=bibtex, abnt-emphasize=bf]{abntex2cite}   
\usepackage{natbib}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm} 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm, footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry}      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
%\usepackage{algcompatible}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicand}{\textbf{ and }}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicor}{\textbf{ or }}
\algnewcommand{\OR}{\algorithmicor}
\algnewcommand{\AND}{\algorithmicand}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\makeatletter

\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={\@title},
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo}, 
    pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
    pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{trabalho acadêmico},
    colorlinks=true,            
        linkcolor=black,            
        citecolor=blue,             
        filecolor=black,            
    urlcolor=black,
    bookmarksdepth=4,
    breaklinks=true
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfontsize}{\large}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfont}{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsectionfont}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal document that replicates this behaviour? There are many packages that might be involved with what you currently show, and it would not be possible to replicate it without some hassle. Rather help us help you get it right the first time. A minimal document should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allows us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly wht you're seeing. Can you do that?

Comment: Basically you need more room for `\numberline` to work.  Since putting `Figure` into `\numberline` is not standard, odds are you are calling tocloft or otherwise modifying `\l@figure`.  We need to see that code to fix it.